# How do I compare smalldatetime in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select only rows that occurred within the last 12 hours. The below query works fine without the Where clause, I get exactly what I want for the "Called_At" column. But when I add the where clause it gives me the error `"Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type."`

The query is

```
SELECT TOP (2000) 
      CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONCAT([Call_Date],' ',[Call_Time])) As 'Called_At'
      ,[Other_Column1]
      ,[Other_Column2]
      ,[etc]

  FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table]
  WHERE CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONCAT([Call_Date],' ',[Call_Time])) >= DATEADD(hour,-12,GetDATE())
  ORDER BY [Call_Date] DESC, [Call_Time] DESC
```

Here is a sample of the columns without the Where part of the statement.

```
Called_At             Column1       Column2
-------------------   -------       ---------
2020-04-05 23:09:00   Data          MoreData    
2020-04-05 20:50:00   Data          MoreData
2020-04-05 17:08:00   Data          MoreData
2020-04-05 16:49:00   Data          MoreData
```

Why does the first CONVERT() statement work fine but the second one doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the order of operations.  I would suggest that you find the offensive values using:

```
SELECT CONCAT([Call_Date], ' ', [Call_Time]))
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Table]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(smalldatetime, CONCAT([Call_Date], ' ', [Call_Time])) IS NULL
```

Once you see what the data looks like, you can figure outhow to fix it.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. Someone (who was probably very tired) entered "24" as an hour. This explains why I couldn't convert the column type earlier.